# How to identify extra OpenVMS terminal sessions and then terminate them?

Tags: openvms

[OpenVMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) [DCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIGITAL_Command_Language) command shows that I have three session active.

```
$ show users
  OpenVMS User Processes at 12-OCT-2014 20:44:29.57
Total number of users = 3,  number of processes = 6

Username  Node     Interactive  Subprocess   Batch
CWHII     ROSIE            3
EFRICHA   ROSIE            1
HEINER    ROSIE            2
```

How do I identify the two old ones and then terminate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, I typically use ^T (control-T) to see 'who am I' and $ SHOW US CWHII/FULL.
Then shoot to kill as needed.

If we assume 'old', to mean NOT the current session, then you script that as follows:

```
$ type CLEAN_ME_UP.COM
$ ctx  = ""
$ this = F$GETJPI( "", "PRCNAM" )
$ user = F$GETJPI( "", "USERNAME" )
$ node = F$GETJPI( "", "NODENAME" )
$ temp = F$CONTEXT( "PROCESS", ctx, "USERNAME", user, "EQL" )
$ temp = F$CONTEXT ("PROCESS", ctx, "NODENAME", node, "EQL")
$! IF F$TYPE( ctx ) .NES. "PROCESS_CONTEXT" THEN EXIT
$loop:
$ pid  = F$PID( ctx )
$ IF pid .EQS. "" THEN EXIT
$ that = F$GETJPI( pid, "PRCNAM" )
$ IF this.EQS.that
$ THEN
$  WRITE SYS$OUTPUT pid, " new"
$ ELSE
$  WRITE SYS$OUTPUT pid, " old"
$ ENDIF
$ GOTO loop
```

- Of course you want to replace the WRITE SYS$OUTPUT with STOP/ID once satisfied.
- Remove the NODE context if you want to do this for all older processes on every node.
- Consider  F$GETJPI( "", "LOGINTIM") if you really want to use 'older' (shoot in foot?)

Cheers,
Hein

re-formatted:

```
$ ctx  = ""
$ this = F$GETJPI( "", "PRCNAM" )
$ temp = F$CONTEXT( "PROCESS", ctx, "USERNAME", F$GETJPI("","USERNAME"), "EQL" )
$ temp = F$CONTEXT ("PROCESS", ctx, "NODENAME", F$GETJPI("","NODENAME"), "EQL")
$! IF F$TYPE( ctx ) .NES. "PROCESS_CONTEXT" THEN EXIT
$loop:
$ pid  = F$PID( ctx )
$ IF pid .EQS. "" THEN EXIT
$ IF F$GETJPI( pid, "PRCNAM" ).NES.F$GETJPI("", "PRCNAM") THEN WRITE SYS$OUTPUT "STOP ",pid
$ GOTO loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Identify all of the processes you are running.

```
$ SHOW USER CWHII/FULL
      OpenVMS User Processes at 13-OCT-2014 16:13:46.49
    Total number of users = 1,  number of processes = 3

 Username  Node   Process Name    PID     Terminal
 CWHII     ROSIE  CWHII         20200117  TZA44:   (108.225.238.117)
 CWHII     ROSIE  _TZA18:       202000B4  TZA18:   (108.225.238.117)
 CWHII     ROSIE  _TZA33:       202000C9  TZA33:   (108.225.238.117)
```

Identify the current one's Process Name by requesting a DCL interrupt and status report by doing a Control-T.

```
$ ^T
ROSIE::CWHII 16:13:49   (DCL)   CPU=00:02:48.66 PF=15943 IO=9693 MEM=245
```

Kill the two that do not have that Process Name.

```
$ STOP/IDENTIFICATION=202000B4
$ STOP/IDENTIFICATION=202000C9
```

The lower PIDs on the two confirm that they are the older processes.

This is information for an interactive method for reference w/o using a script based upon the information in [Hein](https://superuser.com/users/378925/hein)'s answer.